# Redhat virsh console vmname hangs (no network connectivity)

Tags: linux, console, redhat, virsh

I am currently trying to console into my redhat linux vm using: **virsh console** *GuestVM* but the console just hangs when I type the command. I tried pressing "enter" but that didn't work. Also, I cannot ping it's IP address or hostname. So, I cannot ssh into it. Any tips? I tried virt-manager to get a GUI going but the guest VM does not have X Windows System Desktop installed.

I checked the VM's xml and saw that the console is configured with the following:

```
<console type='pty' tty='/dev/pts/1'>
  <source path='/dev/pts/1'/>
  <target type='serial' port='0'/>
  <alias name='serial0'/>
```

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming related questions only. Please review the [help/on-topic] for what topics can be asked here. This question may be appropriate on other SE sites such as [Superuser](http://superuser.com). Check their help first to see if the question belongs there and if so you can click the "flag" link and select "in need of moderator attention" to request migration there.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

The `virsh console` command connects you to the virtual serial port in the guest. If you see nothing on this console this indicates that the guest OS has not setup anything on the serial port. Typically in Linux you'd want to make it run an 'agetty' process on the serial port. If you want to see kernel boot messages on this serial console you also need to edit the guest boot loader to add `console=tty0 console=ttyS0` to the kernel command line - this should get boot messages on both the serial and graphical consoles.